# Apache Scoop import qualified table from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cloudera, sqoop

When I try to import a table from SQL Server using

```
sqoop import \
  -m 1 \
 --connect jdbc:sqlserver://Arwen:1433 \
 --username=bods \
 --password=***\
 --table datamart.dbo.fct_txn
 --compression-codec=snappy \
 --as-avrodatafile \
 --warehouse-dir=/user/tkidb
```

sqoop seems to create a wrong query syntax. Apparently it expects an unqualified table name. Then the brackets would work. How to tackle this?

```
16/06/25 07:44:55 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/06/25 07:44:57 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [datamart.dbo.fct_txn] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/06/25 07:44:57 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'datamart.dbo.fct_txn'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a query from error log:

```
SELECT t.* FROM [datamart.dbo.fct_txn] AS t WHERE 1=0
```

The problem is in quotes around `[datamart.dbo.fct_txn]` the correct syntax must be `[datamart].[dbo].[fct_txn]` or `datamart.dbo.fct_txn`. Try to change two strings:

```
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://Arwen:1433;database=datamart' \
--table fct_txn
```

If `datamart` is default DB for the user you are trying to login, then change only *table* part.